# Grouping influx data per day using flux

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I have been wrangling with a time grouping issue in influxDB using the flux query language. I can illustrate with generated data, one entry per day from 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-05.

```
import "generate"
data = generate.from(
  count: 5,
  fn: (n) => n + 1,
  start: 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z,
  stop: 2021-01-06T00:00:00Z,
)

data
  |> range(start: 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2021-01-05T05:00:00Z)
```

that generates:

| _table | _value | _start | _stop | _time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |
| 0 | 2 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | 2021-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 0 | 3 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | 2021-01-03T00:00:00.000Z |
| 0 | 4 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | 2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z |
| 0 | 5 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z |

now I query the data and aggregate per day

```
import "generate"
data = generate.from(
count: 5,
  fn: (n) => n + 1,
  start: 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z,
  stop: 2021-01-06T00:00:00Z,
)
data
  |> range(start: 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2021-01-05T23:59:00Z)
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
```

I get this

| _table | _value | _start | _stop | _time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | **2021-01-02T00:00:00.000Z** |
| 0 | 2 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | 2021-01-03T00:00:00.000Z |
| 0 | 3 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | 2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z |
| 0 | 4 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | **2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z** |
| 0 | 5 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z | **2021-01-05T23:59:00.000Z** |

the first time is `2021-01-02T00:00:00.000Z` and not `2021-01-01` and the two last entries cover the same day `2021-01-05`.

how can I get the entries per day as below using flux:

- 2021-01-01 - 1
- 2021-01-02 - 2
- 2021-01-03 - 3
- 2021-01-04 - 4
- 2021-01-05 - 5

Comment: Same question here. It seems the aggregate `every: 1d` calculates back from the current time so the `1d` slices are not aligned to time 00:00 until 23:59 ... but no idea how to solve this with flux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to change/add the `timeSrc` parameter in your `aggregateWindow` window function. By default, Flux will use `_stop` as value of the parameter, creating "high" bound windows.

Let's make your example a bit simpler with the time not being exact at day end/start for better illustration: If for instance, it is 22:20 system time, I issue a query with range "-1h" and group by 1h, Flux will create two tumbling time windows: 21:00-22:00 and 22:00-23:00. In fact, Flux detects its range and truncates those global time windows to 21:20-22:00 and 22:00-22:20.

If now, aggregateWindow timeSrc is set to _stop, the time column will be 22:00 and 22:20. [the end of each previously mentioned time windows]. If you chose "_start", the time column will be 21:20 and 22:00.

If you want 21:00 and 22:00 in the above example, I suggest adjusting your range to something like: `range(start: date.truncate(t: -24h, unit: 1h)` which usually also makes more sense that having a first bucket also contains all the data from that bucket.

Answer (score 0):

one way I found to achieve this was using map with strings.substring function to format the date

```
import "strings"

start_time = -30d
bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
metric_name = "your-metric-name"

range_query = from(bucket: bucket_name)
  |> range(start: start_time)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == metric_name)
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: count)
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ day: strings.substring(v: string(v: r["_time"]), start: 0, end: 10), count: r["_value"] }))
```

generated the following result:

| day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-01 | 1 |
| 2023-03-02 | 0 |
| 2023-03-03 | 10 |